# Extracting depth data of nodes of unstructured mesh in QGIS

Tags: qgis, extract, nodes, mesh, depth

I am currently working on a project which requires unstructured meshing of a given area. Also, i need to extract the data such as nodes x-y coordinates, cell data (triangular cells in my case) and depth at each node.

I am using QGIS for this. I was able to generate mesh through the QGIS-GMSH plugin. I am also able to extract the nodes and cell data but I am unable to extract the depth data.

I have googled a lot to find a solution, but till now, no luck.

Comment: Is your depth data held within the mesh or in a separate dataset?  Are your nodes a point shapefile? Would you be able to put up an image showing an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use QGIS 3.18 and QGIS Mesh Layer, you can use Processing Toolbox > Mesh to export the data to raster or vector data format

[image: QGIS Processing Toolbox for Mesh]